# Construct command for bash exec

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, exec

I have a shell script that runs `exec` to replace itself with another command.  The other command takes some optional arguments.

```
exec mycommand $ARG1 $ARG2 $ARG3
```

Any of these arguments could be populated or not populated.  If they aren't populated, they don't render as an argument to the function.  For example:

```
# if you have:
ARG1=foo
ARG3=bar
exec mycommand $ARG1 $ARG2 $ARG3
# then you get:
exec mycommand foo bar
```

However, I want spaces to be legal in the values for these arguments, and for this not to cause them to produce additional arguments.  That is,

```
# if you have
ARG1="foo bar baz"
ARG2="qux"
exec mycommand $ARG1 $ARG2 $ARG3
# then I want:
exec mycommand "foo bar baz" qux
# not:
exec mycommand foo bar baz qux
```

I tried putting escaped quotes into the arguments, but exec expected them to literally be part of the value.

```
ARG1="\"foo bar baz\""
exec mycommand $ARG1 $ARG2 $ARG3
# gives you:
exec mycommand \"foo bar baz\"
```

I also tried quoting the variables in exec, but then it started passing empty strings when arguments weren't present:

```
ARG2="foo bar"
exec mycommand "$ARG1" "$ARG2" "$ARG3"
# gives you:
exec mycommand "" "foo bar" ""
```

Is there a better way to construct a command and pass it to exec?  Is there another way to replace the current process with another one?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- how to store a command in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash, you use an array, and all variables must be properly quoted:

```
ARG1="foo bar baz"
ARG3="qux"

cmd=( mycmd )

[[ -n "$ARG1" ]] && cmd+=( "$ARG1" )
[[ -n "$ARG2" ]] && cmd+=( "$ARG2" )
[[ -n "$ARG3" ]] && cmd+=( "$ARG3" )

printf "%s\n" "${cmd[@]}"
#exec "${cmd[@]}"
```

This will give you the invocation you want: `exec mycommand "foo bar baz" qux`
with no "empty string" arguments. Remove the printf line and uncomment the exec line if you're happy with how it's working.